# Debugging LLVM Pass with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, llvm, clang, visual-studio-debugging

I have llvm set up on windows. Is it possible to use the Visual Studio Debugger to debug my pass. (in the lib/Transforms directory)

Comment: Go through this tutorial, you will be able to achieve what you want [https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, surely. Just put breakpoints on the functions of interest.

Comment: But how do I run a pass from inside visual studio? For eg. what would be the steps to run LLVMHello pass from inside visual studio?

Comment: You cannot run Hello pass as-is (via opt -load), because there is no dynamic linking on windows. However, if you will link your pass inside opt as all standard passes do, then you can debug opt and run your pass from within.

Comment: I am sorry I am somewhat new to llvm on windows. If you don't mind, could you please explain how to specifically link LLVMhello with opt?